# How to use an array (and assign values to it) after it has been previously initialized?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Let's say this is my code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int[] text = new int[0];
        for (int i = 0; v<example.length(); i++) {
            int text[] = {maybe.indexOf(example)
        };
    }
}
```

How could I make it that the array inside the `for` loop is just overwriting the array `text[]` that was initialized before it? Right now I'm getting the error that Java can't find the symbol `text3` in my `for` loop. I want to initialize the array `text[]` before it has all the values determined in the `for` loop so I can use it for the rest of my program.

Comment: Ignore the "int" inside the for loop next to "text[]"

Comment: The error message doesn't make sense if looking at your code. Try to simply copy and paste it (properly formatted) into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write to it:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int[] text = new int[example.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < example.length(); i++) {
            text[i] = maybe.indexOf(example);
        }
    }
}
```

`text[i]` writes to the `ith+1` place in the array (C-style arrays start counting at 0 - for complicated reasons involving memory reference locations).